# Azure devops how to archive multiple folders without duplicating ArchiveFiles task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have multiple folders that I want to archive and publish as a zip folder. I have 3 folders and don't want to create 3 Archive Files tasks. Is it possible to archive multiple folder with a single task?

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'folder1'
    includeRootFolder: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
```

when I tried

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'folder1','folder2','folder3'
    includeRootFolder: false
```

got an invalid yaml structure error. is it even possible to Archive multiple folders in a single task? I also don't want to Archive the root folder as theres other files that don't need to be archived

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible with this task. The only option is probably to copy all necessary folders under the same root folder prior to archiving.